# Waiting in Selenium tests after Create webdriver in current thread

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I have been question about selenium test with chrome headless variant.
Sometimes test is waiting anything, why is it has long time 10 minutes?
I added into tests timeout 40 sec.

```
15:41:54 INFO: Selenium WebDriver v. 3.14.0 build time: 2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z
15:41:54 Oct 12, 2018 12:41:55 PM com.codeborne.selenide.impl.WebDriverThreadLocalContainer createDriver
15:41:54 INFO: Create webdriver in current thread 1: ChromeDriver -> ChromeDriver: chrome on LINUX (6332d1a2dee8e95f05da4130b99237f9)
15:51:54 [34mEmbed Failed timeout
15:51:54   (Session info: chrome=69.0.3497.100)
15:51:54   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
15:51:54 Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

Selenium settings:

```
    case "chrome":
        testBrowserName = "CH";
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
        ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
        WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

You havn't mentioned about your *usecase* in details and it is not clear why you would use restrict your tests to **ChromeDriver** implementation only.

If you use `ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();` the *ChromeDriver* instance which will get created will be only able to invoke and act on the methods implemented by *ChromeDriver* and supported by *Chrome Browser* only. To act with other browsers you have to specifically create individual objects as below :

- `FirefoxDriver driver =  new FirefoxDriver();`
- `InternetExplorerDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();`

### WebDriver Interface

From *Selenium* perspective, the **WebDriver Interface** is similar like a agreement which the 3rd party *Browser Vendors* like *Mozilla*, *Chrome*, *Internet Explorer*, *Safari*, etc have to adhere and implement the same. This would in-turn help the end-users to use the exposed APIs to write a common code and implement the functionalities across all the available *Browsers* without any change.

You will find a detailed discussion in [what is the difference between ChromeDriver and WebDriver in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium)

### Solution

Instead of using the **ChromeDriver** implementation switch to the **WebDriver Interface**. As per current scenario, we have to instantiate the implementations of *WebDriver Interface* directly. The current practice is, we need to write our *Automated Test Script* against this interface so that in future we may swap in a more fully featured Browser when there is a requirement for one.

Example:

```
case "chrome":
    testBrowserName = "CH";
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless");
    chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
    WebDriverRunner.setWebDriver(driver);
    break;
```